# C# Excel Find Function Exception

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am trying to create a C# app which accesses an Excel worksheet using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

I am able to successfully load a worksheet and read the data, however, when I use the find function, I get an exception

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sheetName);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
Excel.Range colRange = xlWorksheet.Columns["A"];
Excel.Range resultRange = colRange.Find(row[2].ToString(), null, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, false, Type.Missing);
```

(I know for sure row[2] is initialized and successfully uses ToString())

The exception looks like:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.dll
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Find(Object What, Object After, Object LookIn, Object LookAt, Object SearchOrder, XlSearchDirection SearchDirection, Object MatchCase, Object MatchByte, Object SearchFormat)
   at ServiceBOMVATool.MainWindow.EnterModel_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\ta4935\source\repos\ServiceBOMVATool\ServiceBOMVATool\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 445
```

Would anyone know what could possibly be going wrong? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I guess xlWorksheet.Columns["A"] must be the range. Can u plz try and confirm ?

Comment: @PraveenRai i changed this and still threw the same exception

Comment: Ok, and which how did you get rows ? colRange.Find(  row[2]    .ToString(), null,.....

Comment: row is from a datatable which contains data from a SQL query I am comparing to the excel worksheet in column A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `null` as the second parameter (for parameter `After`). But `null` is not a valid value here. If you don't want to pass this parameter, use `Type.Missing` as you already do for the last parameter:

```
Excel.Range resultRange = colRange.Find(
    row[2].ToString(), 
    Type.Missing, // Null is not allowed here
    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, 
    Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, 
    Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, 
    false, 
    false, 
    Type.Missing);
```

As an alternative, just specify the parameters you want to use by name. This will automatically use `Type.Missing` for all parameters that are not specified.

```
// Specifiy parameters by name to leave out some
Excel.Range resultRange = colRange.Find(
    What: row[2].ToString(),
    LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
    LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
    SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
    SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
    MatchCase: false,
    MatchByte: false);
```